# xaxis of type date displaying in reverse order react-plotly.js

Tags: reactjs, plotly.js

I am plotting a bar chart with the slider range using react-plotly.js. The xaxis type of the chart is date. I feed in the axis range using a timepicker. When I select the time to be " today" i.e end time in the future, the chart display the xaxis in a reverse order. 
[image]

Also, you will notice that it doesn't display any bars even though there exists data during that timerange. Is this an issue with the date format  ? or plotly doesn't work with the future date ?
My plot configuration looks like :

```
const layout = {
        title: this.state.chartTitle,
        autosize: true,
        dragmode: false,
        margin: {
          r: 0,
          t: 50,
          b: 100,
          pad: 0,
          autoexpand: true
        },
        hoverlabel: {
          bgcolor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
          bordercolor: 'rgba(200,200,200,1)'
        },
        width: this.state.layoutWidth,
        height: '750',
        yaxis: {

          type: 'linear',
          showgrid: true
        },
        xaxis: {
          type: 'date',
          autorange: false,
          fixedrange: false, // true disables range selection on main graph
          showgrid: false,
          range: this.state.axisRange,
          rangeslider: {
            visible: true,
            range: this.state.sliderRange   
          }
        }
```

Also, the time that I am feeding in is in unix format. Before applying to plotly, I am converting it to the datetime format. Is the format that I am applying to the chart correct ?

`axisRange: [moment(1544418000000).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'), moment(1544590799000).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')],`